# What is the jack near my power jack on a toshiba satellite

Tags: toshiba-laptop

I am really curious about the jack near my laptop's power jack. It looks like a mini-usb jack but it sure isn't.  What is it?

Laptop model: Toshiba Satellite c660d-16e

Comment: WIthout a picture, or at least the type/model of the laptop this is impossible, to tell.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including equipment information (i.e. brand and model numbers). If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: it is a toshiba satellite c660d-16e

Comment: @CharlieRB Obviously didn't read the manual that came with the laptop :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually a jack.  According to page 38 of [this link](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwispoGe87bLAhWEnqYKHUJJCyYQFggxMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mytoshiba.co.nz%2Ffile%2Fdownload%2Fresource%2Ffile%2F18989%2Fsat%2520c660-pro%2520c660_userguide.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGG-5jH5-B3zCtNc2ZYRvBhqqm3Aw&bvm=bv.116573086,d.dGY) it is a security [lock port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot).

[image]

Comment: @Techie007 Damn... You beat me to it by about 10 seconds.